# What is your idea for a good AI project for a group of undergraduates?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

There are two courses: "AI" and "AI in Games" both 15 students for 15 weeks.
I want to keep them motivated and creative.
I know I want some kind of competition (obvious for the latter course). 
Maybe something like Marathon Match or ICFP.
I will need good visualization, so it would be great if it already exist.
One idea was to write AI for "Battle of Wesnoth", but I guess it's to diverse / boring.
Another game of Go. But that's too hard.

What are your ideas?

It will be work in groups of 3 students for 15 weeks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MIT hosts a competition called [BattleCode](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506215719/http://battlecode.mit.edu/2009/info).

> BattleCode, is a real-time strategy
>   game. Two teams of robots roam the
>   screen managing resources and
>   attacking each other with different
>   kinds of weapons. However, in
>   BattleCode each robot functions
>   autonomously; under the hood it runs a
>   Java virtual machine loaded up with
>   its team's player program. Robots in
>   the game communicate by radio and must
>   work together to accomplish their
>   goals.
>
> Teams of one to four students enter
>   are given the BattleCode software and
>   a specification of the game rules.
>   Each team develops a player program,
>   which will be run by each of their
>   robots during BattleCode matches.
>   Contestants often use artificial
>   intelligence, pathfinding, distributed
>   algorithms, and/or network
>   communications to write their player.
>   At the final tournaments, the
>   autonomous players are pitted against
>   each other in a dramatic head-to-head
>   tournament. The final rounds of the
>   MIT tournament are played out in front
>   of a live audience, with the top teams
>   receiving cash prizes.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mit.edu](http://battlecode.mit.edu/2009/img/battlecode-screenshot.png))</sub>

*BattleCode in action.*

You essentially are given the BattleCode software from MIT and your students can program the AI for their robots.  They have a test suite so you can practice running your autonomous bots on your own in a practice arena.  Towards the end of the semester they can enter in [MIT's Open Tournament](https://web.archive.org/web/20100701161000/http://battlecode.mit.edu/2009/tournaments/index), where they compete with their software AI robots against schools all over the nation.  Up to $40,000 is given away in cash and prizes as well as bragging rights for winning.

If you are looking to teach them about [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubberband_effect), [Pathfinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding), [Swarm Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence), etc. I can't think of a more fun way.

May the best AI bot win!

Comment: My schools ACM chapter is entering in BattleCode this year.  That would be cool to see another team from SO.

Comment: That might happen indeed :) Thanks for this great link.
(We did ORTS two years ago)

Answer (score 2):

Wii [gesture recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesture_recognition) using [hidden markov models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't count out Go.  It's computationally hard for Go AI to compete with top human players, but the simple rules of Go (compared to Chess) make it a relatively easy game to write AI for.  Your students' programs only need to compete against each other, not against [Dan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_ranks_and_ratings#Kyu_and_Dan_ranks) level human players.  See [An Introduction to the Computer Go Field and Associated Internet Resources](http://www.itee.uq.edu.au/~janetw/Computer%20Go/CS-TR-339.html) for a lot of Go programming resources.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good idea to select a theme both challenging enough that it can't be completely solved, yet allows the user to see the value of it in the real world and not so much a toy problem. My suggestion would thus be:

1. Word segmentation problem (e.g. convert "iamaboy" to "i'am a boy")
2. Word sense disambiguation (e.g. "The apple is nice to eat" - The apple is a fruit or a company?)
3. Optical character recognition

What I just list down is some of the more basic stuff of natural language processing. If your students is much more technically inclined, you can probably take it to the next level and let them tackle the problem of machine translation.

Comment: Word clustering is also good for a short project. Take a large amount of text, and automatically learn clusters for the words that occur, e.g. (a, the, an, of, in) might be in one, while (table, language, street) are in another, etc. It gets more interesting if the clusters are more fine-grained.

Comment: Yea, word clustering is pretty interesting too. Makes me so wanna join the class! :D

Answer (score 0):

[Empire](http://www.classicempire.com/), it's [addictive](http://www.classicempire.com/letters.html) as [whatever](http://www.classicempire.com/epyx.html) and there are open source [D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/) versions ([1](ftp://ftp.classicempire.com/empiresrc.zip) and [2](ftp://ftp.classicempire.com/stewart.zip)) and a [not quite free c++ version](http://www.classicempire.com/shop.html) .